# How to reload/refresh a react-table component from my form component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I have two reactJS components:

1. CustomerForm component with a form and form handling code.
2. CustomerList component which lists the customers using react-table.

Both components are functional and I can use the form to add data to the database, and then fetch and display data in react-table.

But I can't figure out how to refresh the react-table data on successful form submission.

I am loading the components directly into an HTML page and using babel to process JSX. I am just starting our with reactJS and more used to PHP/jQuery development, so maybe I am approaching this wrong. Would appreciate any feedback.

My code:

**CustomerForm**

```
class CustomerForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: [], name: '', phone: '', nameErr: '', phoneErr: ''};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const name = target.name;
        this.setState({[name]: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var self = this;

        axios.post(APP_URL + '/customer/add', {
            name: this.state.name,
            phone: this.state.phone
        }).then(function (response) {
            //console.log(response);
            var data = response.data;
            if (data.status === 0) {
                if (typeof data.payload === 'object') {
                    for (var key in data.payload) {
                        if (data.payload[key]) {
                            self.setState({[key]: data.payload[key]});
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <div className="container mt-3">
                    <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-6">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>Name</label>
                                    <input name="name" type="text" className={'form-control ' + (this.state.nameErr ? 'is-invalid' : '')} placeholder="Enter name"  value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                    <div className="invalid-feedback">{this.state.nameErr}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <label>Email address</label>
                                    <input name="phone" type="text" className="form-control" placeholder="Enter phone"  value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                                </div>
                                <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>

                );
    }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#CustomerFormContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(CustomerForm), domContainer);
```

**Customer List**

```
class CustomerList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {data: [], loading: false, pages: null};
        this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    }

    fetchData(state, instance) {
        var self = this;

        this.setState({loading: true});

        axios.post(APP_URL + '/customer/index', {
            page: state.page,
            pageSize: state.pageSize,
            sorted: state.sorted,
            filtered: state.filtered
        }).then(function (response) {
            // handle success
            self.setState({
                data: response.data.payload,
                pages: 1,
                loading: false
            });
        }).catch(function (error) {
            // handle error
            console.log(error);
        }).finally(function () {
            // always executed
        });
    }

    render() {
        const {data, pages, loading} = this.state;
        return (
                <div className="container mt-3">
                    <ReactTable
                        columns={[
                                    {
                                        Header: "Name",
                                        accessor: "name"
                                    },
                                    {
                                        Header: "Phone",
                                        accessor: "phone"
                                    }
                                ]}
                        manual
                        data={this.state.data}
                        pages={this.state.pages} 
                        loading={this.state.loading} 
                        onFetchData={this.fetchData} 
                        defaultPageSize={10}
                        className="-striped -highlight"
                        />
                    <br />
                </div>
                );
    }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#CustomerListContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(CustomerList), domContainer);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

Render both components in a parent component. [Lift the table state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) and pass a function to the form that will call the function to fetch data.

---

First of all, one quick tip. Render only one component in one `div` and then nest all the other components inside.

In both files, you are rendering the component in diferent selectors

**CustomerForm**

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#CustomerFormContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(CustomerForm), domContainer);
```

**Customer List**

```
const domContainer = document.querySelector('#CustomerListContainer');
ReactDOM.render(e(CustomerList), domContainer);
```

This isn't good because this way, it's not easy to share state and props between then.

What you should do is have a root component that render both components.

```
class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <CustomerForm />
            <CustomerList />
        )
    }
}

const domContainer = document.querySelector('#app');
ReactDOM.render(e(App), domContainer);
```

**OBSERVATION** 
I'm not sure what is the `e` function and why you are using, but I assume this won't change anything, but please, specify what it is.

Doing this, you can share state and props between components.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: [], loading: false, pages: null };
    this.fetchData = this.fetchData.bind(this);
    this.reloadData = this.reloadData.bind(this);
  }

  reloadData() {
    this.fetchData(state);
  }

  fetchData(state, instance) {
    var self = this;

    this.setState({ loading: true });

    axios
      .post(APP_URL + "/customer/index", {
        page: state.page,
        pageSize: state.pageSize,
        sorted: state.sorted,
        filtered: state.filtered
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        // handle success
        self.setState({
          data: response.data.payload,
          pages: 1,
          loading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // handle error
        console.log(error);
      })
      .finally(function() {
        // always executed
      });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CustomerForm reloadData={reloadData} />
        <CustomerList data={data} pages={pages} loading={loading} fetchData={fetchData} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here what I'm doing is called [Lifting State Up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html). I'm getting the state of `CustomerList` to the parent component so you can reload the data when the form calls `reloadData`.

This way you also need to change `CustomerList` to get the data from `this.props` and in `CustomerForm` call `reloadData` when the submit is success.

**Customer List**

```
  render() {                                   // getting from props
    const { data, pages, loading, fetchData } = this.props;
    return (
      <div className="container mt-3">
        <ReactTable
          columns={[
            {
              Header: "Name",
              accessor: "name"
            },
            {
              Header: "Phone",
              accessor: "phone"
            }
          ]}
          manual
          data={data}
          pages={pages}
          loading={loading}
          onFetchData={fetchData}
          defaultPageSize={10}
          className="-striped -highlight"
        />
        <br />
      </div>
    );
  }
```

**CustomerForm**

Call `this.props.reloadData()` when the submit is success.

*I don't know when you want to reload the data, it's not clear when is a succes.